# ListView doesn't show any added items

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to add some items to ListView - they aren't showing.

*I realize this question has been asked many times, but I tried to follow any advice I found there - none worked for me.*

Here is content of my **onCreate** method of **public class MyListActivity extends AppCompatActivity** ->

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

ListView view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
view.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.add("aaaaa");
adapter.add("bbbbb");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And here's my associated layout XML ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.kuba.myapplication3.MyListActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@string/txt_searching"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ButtonTxt" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Well and like I said, "aaaa" and "bbbb" don't show anywhere.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Can you show your adapter declaration ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam It's in MyListActivity class as private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activity code is perfect. The **problem** is in your **layout file** and very silly one.

You set your **main** **LinearLayout** background as `background_dark`. And your **ListView Text color** is also dark. So it is not visible.

Try background color as `background_light` and your ListView will be visible.

Or, If you want to change ListView Text Color then do as following:

1) Create a **Custom Layout** as below : (custom_list_layout.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvlist"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

2) Set this to your **Array Adapter**:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.custom_list_layout);
```

Then your ListView with white text will be visible in dark background. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well I like silly mistakes, because it means there isn't some severe problem. I can't try it right now, but I'm going to do it ASAP, then get back to you. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It did not help. I tried the light background, but it visually didn't change at all. Looks like the whole ListView isn't being added to the activit, not just its items into it.

Comment: I actually ran all the code you provided on my device. First I copied your activity code and it worked fine. Then I copied the xml code, There was a dark background that's why listview wasn't visible. Changed it and it worked again. May b you are using duplicate xml file or something. You may provide full activity code.

Comment: Well I ran it again today and it works.. I was probably too tired yesterday and missed something stupid. Anyway the dark background of both activity and listview was my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I see you are initializing the adapter without a reference to its set of items and it may be the problem. Please try this code instead:

**Class field:**

```
private List<String> items;
```

**onCreate method:**

```
...

items = new ArrayList<>();

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
view.setAdapter(adapter);
items.add("aaaaa");
items.add("bbbbb");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

...
```

Or you could simply initialize the items list with the two elements instead of adding them later.

Comment: Thanks for fast reaction, but alas it didn't help. Items still don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i think that sometimes UI elements modifications may be executed on another threads. Therefore, maybe when you add elements then notifyDataSetChanged(), views are not shown neither displayed yet, therefore, nothing is done. Then the adapter try to display something and has no elements.

I'g suggest two things :
-First, try to add elements to adapter list (like Juan Martinez answer) BEFORE adapter declaration and `setAdapter(adapter);`. Then create your adapter, set adapter.
-Second, try to add elements and notifyDataSetChanged on "onStart" instead of "onCreate()".

First test will allow you to see if the problem is in constructors, threads, etc. Second test will show you if you can add elements a little later in order to have things working if first test shows that you cannot add elements immediatly after "setAdapter".

It seems that your code is made for example or little tests, so, without knowing where you really need add objects and what is the display problem it may be hard to give you precise code.

on Oncreate method :

```
items = new ArrayList<>();

    items.add("aaaaa");
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    view.setAdapter(adapter);
    items.add("bbbbb");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Override onStart too

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.add("cccc");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

if your view shows only aaaa and cccc, then you cannot add items just after setAdapter. If nothing still show, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I tried all of that, nothing shows up. So as you say problem is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: Instead of adding directly the strings "aaaa" etc, if you try String aString="aaaa";then adding aString to arrayList/adapter, does that work ? Maybe android is trying to add char[] to String arrays, and there is a cast problem without raising exceptions.

Comment: It doesn't throw any kind of error.. nothing simply happens. I'm going to try that, when I have a chance.